# Angular 2: When onChange is triggered, How to retrieve both the selected value and the id of the select element?

Tags: angular, typescript

Here's the code in the template:

```
<select id="regionSelection" [(ngModel)]="regionId"
        (change)="onChange($event.target.value)"
        class = "form-control">
              <option *ngFor="let r of regionsForDDL"
               value="{{ r.key }}">{{ r.value }}</option>
</select>
```

and the code in the component

```
onChange(selectedValue: string) {

}
```

`$event.target.value` only sends the selected value. How do I get both the selected value and the id of the element (here `regionSelection`)?

Thanks for helping

Comment: If you're not generating dynamically <select> tags, you can pass id as a second parameter to onChange function (here (change) = "onChange($event.target.value, 'regionSelection')"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just pass it like this:

```
(change)="onChange($event.target.id, $event.target.value)"

onChange(id: string, selectedValue: string) {

}
```

Answer (score 4):

**html**

```
(change)="onChange($event.target)"
```

**ts**

```typescript
onChange({ id, value }) {
   console.log(id, value);
}
```

or

```typescript
onChange({ id, value: selectedValue }) {
  console.log(id, selectedValue);
}
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7ysmjr?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts

See more details about how destructuring assignment syntax works

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Unpacking_fields_from_objects_passed_as_function_parameter

Comment: you can add the link to destructing explanation https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Unpacking_fields_from_objects_passed_as_function_parameter

Answer (score 1):

Or this by adding a template variable and getting the  value and the id of your element:

```
<select #mySelect id="regionSelection" [(ngModel)]="regionId"
        (change)="onChange(mySelect.value, mySelect.id)"
        class = "form-control">
              <option *ngFor="let r of regionsForDDL"
               value="{{ r.key }}">{{ r.value }}</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

other way is to use a `#template` variable as shown below,

```
<select id="regionSelection" 
        [(ngModel)]="regionId" #target           // added #target
        (change)="onChange(regionId,target.id)"  // changed onChange(regionId,target.id)
         class = "form-control">

               <option *ngFor="let r of regionsForDDL"  
                        value="{{ r.key }}">{{ r.value }}</option>
</select>

onChange(value, id) {
   console.log(value);
   console.log(id);
}
```